# Multiple arrays with similar names, access with variable

Tags: c#

I have these string arrays:

```
  string[] BayReplyArray1 = new string[30];
  string[] BayReplyArray2 = new string[30];
  string[] BayReplyArray3 = new string[30];
... up to 10
```

I want to access them in a loop like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
    BayReplyArray[i] = "test";
}
```

It says BayReplyArray does not exist in the current context. I can see why it's confused but how can I accomplish this?

Comment: You cant do that like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments, they each inspired me in some way. The result ended up using jagged arrays.

```
         // declare jagged array with 3 rows
     string[][] jaggedArray = new string[3][];

     // create new arrays in the jagged array and give them a size
     jaggedArray[0] = new string[5];
     jaggedArray[1] = new string[5];
     jaggedArray[2] = new string[5];

     // this assigns values to the first row
     jaggedArray[0][0] = "test1";
     jaggedArray[0][1] = "  test2  ";
     jaggedArray[0][2] = "test3";
     jaggedArray[0][3] = "test4";
     jaggedArray[0][4] = "test5";

     // this assigns values to the second row
     for (int i = 0; i < jaggedArray[1].Length; i++)
     {
        jaggedArray[1][i] = "tt" + i;
     }

     // this assigns values to the third row
     //jaggedArray[2] = new string[3] { "k1", "k2", "k3" };
     string StrTest = "the:quick:brown: fox ";
     char[] delimiters = new char[] { 'u', ':' };
     jaggedArray[2] = StrTest.Split(delimiters);

     // Print out all elements in the jagged array.
     for (int i = 0; i < jaggedArray.Length; i++)
     {
        string[] innerArray = jaggedArray[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < innerArray.Length; j++)
        {
           // this trims whitespace from all elements in the jagged array
           innerArray[j] = innerArray[j].Trim();
           Console.Write(innerArray[j] + " ");
        }
        // this fires after each row in the jagged array
        Console.WriteLine(i);
     }
```

Answer (score 6):

An easy solution to this would be a multi-dimensional array.

```
string[,] BayReplyArrays = new string[10,30]

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
    {
        BayReplyArrays[i,j] = "test";
    }
}
```

Here's the MSDN guide to multi-dimensional arrays: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
const int NumberOfArrays = 10;
const int NumberOfValuesInEachArray = 30;

// array of arrays (could also use a List)
var AllBayReplyArrays = new string[NumberOfArrays][];

// create each nested array
for (var i = 0; i < NumberOfArrays; i++)
{
    AllBayReplyArrays[i] = new string[NumberOfValuesInEachArray];
}

// set values in each array
for (var i = 0; i < NumberOfArrays; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < NumberOfValuesInEachArray; j++)
    {
        // you can write whatever values you like here, I have added the indices to be able to validate the output
        AllBayReplyArrays[i][j] = String.Format("Test {0}-{1}", i, j);
    }
}

// check the values:
Console.WriteLine("The 5th value of the 1st array should be Test 0-4 (for zero based indexes), it is: {0}", AllBayReplyArrays[0][4]);
Console.Read(); //to pause execution
```

The output is:

> The 5th value of the 1st array should be Test 0-4 (for zero based
>   indexes), it is: Test 0-4

---

Another way to get the same result in a one liner is:

```
var AllBayReplyArrays = Enumerable.Range(0,9).Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0,29).Select(j => String.Format("Test {0}-{1}", i, j)).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

You can use the same two test line at the bottom of the first solution to check this.

Comment: This is what I had in my head, creating the 10 string array vars in a loop rather than individually. I have to give this a try but will it work with this: AllBayReplyArrays[i][j] = String.Split (i, j);

Comment: I don't think it can be done the way that you proposed in the question (naming the variable based on some runtime value - the index of an array in this case). You would either need to name them manually one at a time or use data structures to contain them like an array of arrays or List of arrays or List of Lists (or even using a multi-dimensional array as proposed by @Grungondola).

Comment: @EE_Kraig you are confused. You cant assign string array to string. Split gives array. So you have to assign this array into  jagged array. So something like this is valid `AllBayReplyArrays[i]= String.Split (i, j); `

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers you can create a list of arrays and then loop through it.

```
string[] arrString1 = new string[30];
string[] arrString2 = new string[30];
string[] arrString3 = new string[30];

List<string[]> ListOfArrays = new List<string[]>{ arrString1, arrString2, arrString3};


for (int i = 0; i < ListOfArrays.Count; ++i)
{
   string[] CurrentList = ListOfArrays[i];
   for (int i2 = 0; i2 < CurrentList.Count(); ++i2)
   {
       CurrentList[i2] = "Test";
   }
}
```